# Display a Div like a ToolTip - Div Needs to be Positioned Next to Click Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

linkThis should be simple as I have it 95% done and working.  The issue I am having is the popover will pop right next to where you click on the element vs. just next to it.  So if I click on the "L" in the example below - the popover covers the "nk 1".  I want it to be right next to the 1 and also respect the height location of it too.  As clicking on the top, middle, or bottom of the element changes the positioning also.

Here is a Fiddle to show it in action - https://jsfiddle.net/pfcsc93t/2/

```
<div class="popover-link"><a link that toggles div display>Link 1</a></div>
<div class="popover-link"><a link that toggles div display>Link 2</a></div>
<div class="popover-link"><a link that toggles div display>Link 3</a></div>
etc...
```

Popover that has dynamic content feed based on clicked link - only one exist at a time:

```
<div id="popover">popover content</div>
```

Current jQuery:

```
$( ".popover-link").click( function(event) {
$("#popover").removeClass('hide').css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the mouse x and y position, you'll want to get the offset of the clicked element:

```
$( ".popover-link a").click( function(event) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    $("#popover").removeClass('hide').offset({ top:pos.top, left:pos.left + $(this).width()});
});
```

Note that the click is attached to the anchor element ( selector `.popover-link a`), otherwise `this` would point to the div and use its width instead of the anchor/text width.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfcsc93t/3/)